# Creating certificate with certreq tool where I have csr generated using openssl

Tags: certificate, csr, certreq

I have created CSR using openssl and I want it to be signed by the Microsoft CA using command line with template as webServer.

Comment: Please provide some more details about your environment and what you have tried so far.  Windows versions, generally how you installed Microsoft Cert Services, ect.

Comment: If we have a microsoft CA then we will give the CSR content to get the certificate, using the web as UI. The same I need in command line.

Comment: This is the way to generate. Got it! .. certreq.exe -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer" certifcatesigningrequest.csr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way to generate. Got it! .. On a Microsoft CA server machine issue below command:

```
"certreq.exe -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer" certifcatesigningrequest.csr "
```

Comment: If two templates apply, do you repeat -attrib switch or comma separate after the colon?